# Android build taken much longer in Macbook Pro with M1 Pro chip using Kotlin 1.6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, apple-m1

Lately I've been feeling like my Android project was taking way longer to build (around 2 mins, when it used to build in less than a minute for sure). I'm running Android Studio for arm64, with java processes running on Apple Silicon architecture (checked in the Activity Monitor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone runs into the same problem, it turns out the slow down occurred after updating to Kotlin 1.6.0 (hence the title of the question). I updated the Kotlin version of my project to the Kotlin plugin version in my Android Studio, which was 1.6.10 and the build time went from 2 mins to 20 seconds, when changes where applied.

Comment: Thank you so much. My build time is 5min(even 1 line change) -> 1min

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find answer on this question too but my kotlin version is 1.7.0.

What might be wrong:

1. Adnroid Studio is not for Apple chip(download new one for Apple silicon chip);
2. Change JDK for ARM(File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location in the bottom).
   [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgrSL.png)

3. Gradle version is at least 7.0;